# Parse ics file in Python. Icalendar package doesn't return start/end date and other properties

Tags: python, pandas, icalendar, google-calendar-api

Im trying to parse google calendar (`cal.ics`) using icalendar package and running this script:

```
from icalendar import Calendar, Event
from datetime import datetime

g = open('cal.ics','rb')
gcal = Calendar.from_ical(g.read())
for component in gcal.walk():
        print component.get('summary')
        print component.get('dtstart')

g.close()
```

The output is correct `summary` but instead of `start date` im getting:

```
<icalendar.prop.vDDDTypes object at 0x10bae9b10>
```

Tried replacing `get` with `decoded` like this:

```
    print component.decoded('summary')
    print component.decoded('dtstart')
```

...but got en error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-d6a73c485b11> in <module>()
      8 #        print component.content_line
      9         print component.name
---> 10         print component.decoded('summary')
     11         print component.get('dtstart')
     12 

~/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/icalendar/cal.pyc in decoded(self, name, default)
    238         else:
    239             if default is _marker:
--> 240                 raise KeyError(name)
    241             else:
    242                 return default

KeyError: 'summary'
```

All the docs i found are about adding to the calendar while im trying to parse it and eventually move parts of it into pandas. If you have any ideas/suggestions please help.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem years ago- real source of frustration.  Solution is to do

```
component.get('dtstart').dt
```

In general, when you're having a problem like this, try calling `dir()` on it.